# Asp Core Bootstrap collapse not working in dynamic list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I seem to be being tripped up by something I thought would be quite simple.

I have a list of 120 items that are generated dynamically in a .net Core MVC app and in my View I have the following code

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Application)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Domain)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d-@item.ObjID" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#d-@item.ObjID">
                    Notes
                </button>
                    <div id="d-@item.ObjID" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            @Html.Raw(item.Notes)
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Domain.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-route-id="@item.ObjID">Details</a>
                <a asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-route-id="@item.ObjID">Edit</a>
                <a asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-dark" asp-route-id="@item.ObjID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The button click does not expand or collapse as expected - there is nothing in debug and the rendered HTML looks fine.

JQuery and Bootstrap are working fine elsewhere.

Any ideas anyone ?

*** Update ***

I've changed the code as suggested and it still doesn't work.

I've added the generated HTML below if that helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Home">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="Message" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            

<h1 class="display-4">Use Cases</h1>

<p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form method="get" action="/UseCases">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." class="form-control" name="search" value="test" />
        </div>
        <div class="pl-3">
            <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-outline-primary" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="pl-2">
            <a class="form-control btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases">Back to Full List</a>
        </div>    
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Use Case Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Created By
            </th>
            <th>
                Created On
            </th>
            <th>
                Notes
            </th>
            <th>
                Application
            </th>
            <th>
                Domain
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                rich text test
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                16-03-2021 11:41
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d-132" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#d-132">
                    Notes
                </button>
                    <div id="d-132" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <p>test 1</p>
<p style="padding-left: 40px;">indent 1</p>
<p style="padding-left: 40px;">indent 2</p>
<p><strong>bold text example</strong></p>
<p><span style="color: #ba372a;">red text exmple</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                YorBill
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Details?id=132">Details</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Edit?id=132">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="/UseCases/Delete?id=132">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test Use Case
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                15-02-2021 17:08
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d-129" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#d-129">
                    Notes
                </button>
                    <div id="d-129" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                YorBill
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Details?id=129">Details</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Edit?id=129">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="/UseCases/Delete?id=129">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Test use case for notes
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                15-03-2021 11:00
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d-130" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#d-130">
                    Notes
                </button>
                    <div id="d-130" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            Test notes added to use case

2nd line

last line


                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                YorBill
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Details?id=130">Details</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/UseCases/Edit?id=130">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="/UseCases/Delete?id=130">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on("load", function () {
            $('#Message').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        });

        var closing = true;
        $(function () {
            $("a, input[type=submit], input[type=text], input[type=radio], button[type=submit]").click(function () { closing = false; });
            $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
                if (closing) {
                    $.post('/log/LogOff')
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="/lib/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'lists advlist emoticons',
            advlist_bullet_styles: 'square',
            advlist_number_styles: 'lower-alpha',
            menubar: false,
            width: 600,
            toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | outdent indent | numlist bullist | emoticons'
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the most outer collapse main div?

Comment: @LazZiya I've added the full table code - there isn't an outer div as I didn't think there needed to be one ? I understood the that the div to collapse is targeted by it's ID ? The rendered HTML is exactly as it should be in the Bootstrap examples at their site.

Comment: Working [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/4jLyafhs/) . Make sure data-target & id are same of button and div.

Comment: @Swati It doesn't work when generated dynamically in .net core The values are the same for data-target and id

Comment: you still have `aria-controls="collapseExample"`, make it same as the taret div `aria-controls="@item.ObjID"`

Comment: good spot - no change though I'm afraid ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies but I eventually found the right answer and it was a mixture of two things.

Firstly I replaced references to JQuery and Bootstrap with CDN versions and found the collapsible div started working. The styling was off and there was no transition but it worked. This then led me to remove JQuery and Bootstrap and then install again using [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and I had a working collapsible div with the original code and a local install. So far so good. The positioning of the load of Bootstrap and JQuery is important and I also needed the second call in `_Layout.cshmtl` as detailed below

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
...
</head>
```

before end of `</body>`

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly I discovered that the transition in Bootstrap will not work with `TR` elements. To work around this I replaced all table elements with `DIV`s and styled so it looked like the previous table.

Hope this helps if someone is looking for a solution. None of the answers above solved my problem hence the self answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `ObjID`of type `int`, which is not valid for HTML id property, see [HTML5 id naming rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

> an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.

Just add a letter in front of all `@item.ObjID`:

```cs
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d-@item.ObjID" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="d-@item.ObjID">
                    Notes
</button>
<div id="d-@item.ObjID" class="collapse">
    <div class="card card-body">
        @Html.Raw(item.Notes)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made the changes - no change I'm afraid

Comment: @bhs, it should work by changing `id` attribute of target collapsible element to `d-@item.ObjID`.

Comment: @FeiHan that's exactly what I've done and there is no change. Nothing in dev tools and no indication what might be wrong.

Comment: You can try to do a test with [[the sample code of  Bootstrap collapse plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#example) in your view page, and check if sample code can work well with your referenced js/css files.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **#** from `aria-controls="#d-@item.ObjID"`.

Should be like this:
`<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d-@item.ObjID" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="d-@item.ObjID">`

And the target div something like this: `<div class="collapse" id="d-@item.ObjID"></div>`